# Matplotlib colorbars multiple plt.imshow plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I'm trying to make a big overview plot. To do this I use `plt.imshow` to plot the matrixes of the different densities. The problem is that the colorbar, just doesn't want to work with me. As shown in the figure. So now I have two questions.

- How do I make sure all the plots (in the same color) have the same colorbar range?
- How do I get the second colorbar in the middle of the last two coloms.

[image]

My current code is (To test you can change `eval(data)` to a random matrix):

```py
a = 5
b = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(a, b , figsize=(8.27, 11.69), tight_layout=True, sharey=True, sharex=True, gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0})

data = ['map_sm_', 'map_dens_']
gasf = ['fg10', 'fg20', 'fg30', 'fg50', 'fg70']
dire = ['x', 'z', 'x', 'z']


cm = ['hot', 'viridis']

for col in range(b):
    for row in range(a):
        ax = axs[row, col]
        if col ==0:
            ax.set_ylabel('x (kpc)', fontsize=13)
        if col<2:
            if col == 0:
                data = 'map_sm_' + gasf[row] + dire[col]
            else: 
                data = 'map_sm_' + gasf[row] + dire[col]
            pcm = ax.imshow(eval(data),  norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm[0], interpolation='none', extent=[-17.5,17.5,-17.5,17.5])
        else:
            if col == 2:
                data = 'map_dens_' + gasf[row] + dire[col]
            else: 
                data = 'map_dens_' + gasf[row] + dire[col]
            pcm2 = ax.imshow(eval(data), norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm[2], interpolation='none', extent=[-17.5,17.5,-17.5,17.5])
        if row ==4:
            if col == 0:
                ax.set_xlabel('z (kpc)',  fontsize=13)
            if col == 1:
                ax.set_xlabel('y (kpc)', fontsize=13)
            if col == 2:
                ax.set_xlabel('z (kpc)', fontsize=13)
            if col == 3:
                ax.set_xlabel('y (kpc)', fontsize=13)
        

cb1 = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs[0, :2], location='top', pad=-1.2)
cb2 = fig.colorbar(pcm2, ax=axs[0, 2:4], location='top', pad=- 1.2)


cb1.mappable.set_clim(1E2,1E9)
cb2.mappable.set_clim(1E-5,1E0)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't set the color limits on the colorbar.  Set them on the LogNorm.
2. tight_layout can't do what you want with the colorbar.  Please use constrained_layout (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html).  Though that may not be what you want either because you have fixed-aspect axes so it is not easily possible to make there be no space in either direction.
3. specify all the rows as owning the colorbar via `ax=axs[:, :2]` instead of `ax=axs[0, :2]`.  This helps get the spacing right.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

a = 5
b = 4
fig, axs = plt.subplots(a, b , figsize=(8.27, 9.69),
                        constrained_layout=True, sharey=True,
                        sharex=True)
cm = ['hot', 'viridis']

for col in range(b):
    for row in range(a):
        data = np.random.randn(30, 30)
        ax = axs[row, col]
        if col ==0:
            ax.set_ylabel('x (kpc)', fontsize=13)
        if col<2:
            pcm = ax.imshow(data,  norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=0.1, vmax=100),
                            cmap=cm[0],interpolation='none',
                            extent=[-17.5,17.5,-17.5,17.5])
        else:
            pcm2 = ax.imshow(data, norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=0.2, vmax=200),
                             cmap=cm[1], interpolation='none',
                             extent=[-17.5,17.5,-17.5,17.5])
        if row ==4:
            ax.set_xlabel('z (kpc)',  fontsize=13)


cb1 = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=axs[:, :2], location='top', shrink=0.6)
cb2 = fig.colorbar(pcm2, ax=axs[:, 2:4], location='top', shrink=0.6)

plt.show()
```

You may wish to try `axes_grid` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/axes_grid.html) though it has limitations as well.

[image]

Comment: PS when 3.4 is released, you may want to try subfigure: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/next_whats_new/subfigures.html

Comment: Thank you for your clear response, this really helped me